# Execute Java Code based on list of checkboxes in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I have the following class:

```
public class Utility {

public static void restart(String[] args) {
//Restart logic
}

public static void shutdown(String[] args) {
//Shutdown logic
}
}
```

Both of these methods will take in the statuses of a list of dynamically generated (using a scriplet) checkboxes in my JSP, running on Struts 1.

In my JSP I have:

```
<form action="ActionForm">

<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="XA">
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="SDFS">
... <!--THIS IS GENERATED WITH A SCRIPLET>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="FDFS">

<input type="submit" value="Restart">
<input type="submit" value="Shutdown">
</form>
```

But I am confused on how to write the ActionForm and corresponding Action to handle an array of checkboxes, and determining which method to call since there are two submit buttons.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: what do you mean _How can I check the checkboxes I want_?

Comment: For the first issue you can use hidden text box and once the user selects any check box put the value like comma separated `1,5,7,9`. So once you are submitting you can receive this as string and convert this into array. For second one instead of using two submit buttons, use one field either radio button or dropdown ask the user to choose the operation(restart/shutdown) they want.

Comment: Thanks @VinothKrishnan, this is a great idea, and it works wonders

Answer (score 0):

Since JSP uses HTML, you can make a `<form>`-Tag that has your checkboxes and your buttons. It could look something like this:

```
<form action="handle.jsp" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
  <!-- for how many checkboxes you need. -->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button2">
</form>
```

Now, in `handle.jsp`, check your arguments. If a checkbox is clicked, you will have a parameter entry in the `request`-variable. From the parameter named `"submit"` or how you named the buttons you can see which button is clicked - that parameter will hold the value of the button specified in your HTML form.